Can you emulate rust's Fn trait using type classes?
In Rust, there is no type for functions, but rather an Fn trait that looks something like this:
trait Fn<A: Tuple, R> {
    fn call(self, args: A) -> R;
}

Then the type of a function can be dyn Fn(A) -> R. This helps with compiler optimizations while still being pretty simple to understand.
In functional languages, we can similarly define an Fn type class:
class Fn s a b where
    call : s -> a -> b

But, because there is no concept of Self in type classes, there is no dyn Fn type, which means you have to use generics for everything:
// in Rust 

fn run_with_2(f: &dyn Fn(i32) -> i32) -> i32 {
    f.call(2)
}

struct SomeFnWrapper<A,B>(Box<dyn Fn(A) -> B>);

-- in Haskell 

runWith2 : Callable f Int Int => f -> Int
runWith2 f = call f 2

-- creating `SomeFnWrapper` is impossible in Haskell

Is there a solution to this? Perhaps some clever use of forall I'm not aware of?

I suspect you're looking for existential types.

Why pass foo :: X and use call :: X -> Y -> Z when you could just pass call foo :: Y -> Z in the first place?

A solution with existential types which I personally dislike.
class Callable s a b where
    call :: s -> a -> b

data SomeCallable a b where
    SomeCallable :: forall s . Callable s a b => s -> SomeCallable a b

The reason I dislike this is because there is no real reason for the existential type. Its constructor wraps a value of an unknown callable type s, on which only call can be used, so it's isomorphic to the plain
data SomeCallable a b where
    SomeCallable :: (a -> b) -> SomeCallable a b

At that point, you could directly use a -> b instead. There is nothing to be gained from this complex machinery.
Further, I do not understand the purpose of this. In Rust we have no function types, so using Box<dyn Fn(A) -> B + 'someLifetime> is a necessity. It's far more complex than Haskell, but the only sane way to make function types fit the Rust type system. In Haskell, however, we do have function types, so such a workaround is not needed. So... why trying to translate this Rust idiom into Haskell?

FWIW Rust does have (nameable) function types for functions or closures that don't capture: fn(A) -> B

I think you got your emoji backwards.
// in Rust 
fn run_with_2(f: &dyn Fn(i32) -> i32) -> i32 {
    f.call(2)
}

struct SomeFnWrapper<A,B>(Box<dyn Fn(A) -> B>);

-- in Haskell 
runWith2 :: (Int -> Int) -> Int
runWith2 f = f 2

type SomeFnWrapper = (->)

In Rust you need a ton of machinery because every different closure has its own different type. In Haskell, the machinery is not needed: a single type, which is also the plain function type, describes all the different closures.

-- why not this?
runWith2 :: (Int -> a) -> a
runWith2 f = f 2

Haskell is a different language than Rust. There is no
need for declaring a typeclass for a function - it is built-in into typechecker. If you still insist on having a specific name for a function, consider type aliases:
type F = forall a. Int -> a

runWith2 :: F -> a
runWith2 f = f 2

